# How to export video without the preview window

Tags: render

I am trying to export video from After Effects CC 2019. I add the video to render queue, select quick time format, select output location and click "Render". After Effects exports the video with the preview window. It actually shows the preview window of the "remove grain" effects and renders out with the white frame and the effect is only given withing this window. Why? Why would anyone want to export the PREVIEW FRAME. And why, on earth, would that be a default setting?

How do I export it without the frame?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. In the Remove grain settings just disabled the preview frame. I still don't understand though - it's a PREVIEW frame. Why would AE add it to the rendered video?